# Get error of liblapack while rosmake the tum_ardrone package

Tags: ros, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today, I get the package tum_ardrone and make it, there are two files ardrone_autonomy and tum_ardrone. The first one making was ok, while the tum_ardrone package making failed. It reported that :
I know that is about the liblapack, but I don't know how to fix it, can anybody help me?

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_snrm2' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_dtbsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_zswap' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_crotg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_ccopy' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_sptgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_cptsymm' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_cptherk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_dset' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_zdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_zgemv' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_zhpmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_zcopyConj' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_caxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_dnrm2' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_dtrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_cscal' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_cgerc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_sspmv' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_ctbmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_sger' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_zgbmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_sptsymm' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_ctbsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_ztrmv' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_sdsdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_ssyr' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_zpthemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to `ATL_ssbmv' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/liblapack.so: undefined reference to` ATL_cgemv'
collect2: ld 返回 1
make[4]: *** [../bin/drone_stateestimation] 错误 1
make[4]:正在离开目录 `/home/turtlebot2/ardrone_ws/tum_ardrone/build' make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/drone_stateestimation.dir/all] 错误 2 make[3]:正在离开目录` /home/turtlebot2/ardrone_ws/tum_ardrone/build'
make[2]: *** [all] 错误 2
make[2]:正在离开目录 `/home/turtlebot2/ardrone_ws/tum_ardrone/build' make[1]: *** [all] 错误 2 make[1]:正在离开目录` /home/turtlebot2/ardrone_ws/tum_ardrone'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109496/get-error-of-liblapack-while-rosmake-the-tum_ardrone-package/) by [0525084](https://answers.ros.org/users/9706/0525084/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried installing liblapack-dev ? If you are using ubuntu you can do this :

Install Synaptic Package Manager from Ubuntu Software Center.
From Synaptic Package Manager, search for the following packages :
liblapack-dev
libblas-dev

Add them to install

---

Originally posted by [lppier](https://answers.ros.org/users/11266/lppier/) with karma: 41 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1